# How to get length of int variable as string have builtin function e.g string.length()

Tags: c++

Is there any way to get the length of int variable e.g In string we get the length by simply writing int size = string.length();

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int i = 0;
cout<<"Please Enter the value of i"<<endl;
cin>>i;

//if user enter 123

//then size be 3 . 

// Is it possible to find that size

}
```

Comment: An integer doesn't have a length.  However, a *decimal representation* of that integer does.

Comment: "The length of int variable" (memory size) is fixed in the environment and I don't think there is simple way as you think to get the number of digits of integer.

Comment: "Is it possible to find that size" Yes, just count it by yourself (by your program).

Comment: Note that for decimal numbers, log₁₀ increases by 1 per factor of 10 in the number. That's a relatively common trick.

Comment: Write a function for yourself

Comment: `sprintf` and then `strlen`... that will also account for negative ints.

Comment: If we're converting to a string, `std::to_string(num).length()` is much easier.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <cassert>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main () {
    assert(int(log10(9))   + 1 == 1);
    assert(int(log10(99))  + 1 == 2);
    assert(int(log10(123)) + 1 == 3);
    assert(int(log10(999)) + 1 == 3);
    return 0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

For length i assume you mean the *number of digits* in a number:

```
#include <math.h>  

.....
int num_of_digits(int number)
{  
   int digits;
   if(number < 0)
       number = (-1)*number;
   digits = ((int)log10 (number)) + 1;
   return digits;
 }
```

Or:

```
int num_of_digits(int number)
{
    int digits = 0;
    if (number < 0) number = (-1) * number; 
    while (number) {
        number /= 10;
        digits++;
    }
    return digits;
}
```

Onother option could be this (can works with float too, but the result is not guaranteed):

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <sstream>
 #include <iomanip>
```

...........

```
 int num_of_digits3(float number){
    stringstream ss;
    ss << setprecision (20) << number;
    return ss.str().length();
 }
```

Comment: This fails (I think catastrophically) for negative numbers.

Answer (score 0):

**You have a few options here:**

<sub>(This answer assumes you mean number of printable characters in the integer input)</sub>

1. Read the input as a string and get its length before converting to an int. Note that this code avoids error handling for brevity.

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <sstream>

   using namespace std;

   int main(int argc, char** argv) {
       cout << "Please enter the value of i" << endl;
       string stringIn = "";
       cin >> stringIn;
       cout << "stringIn = " << stringIn << endl;
       size_t length = stringIn.length();
       cout << "input length = " << length << endl;
       int intIn;
       istringstream(stringIn) >> intIn;
       cout << "integer = " << intIn << endl;
   }
   ```
2. Read in an integer and count the digits directly:

   <sub>Many other answer do this using log. I'll give one that will properly count the minus sign as a character.</sub>

   ```
   int length_of_int(int number) {
       int length = 0;
       if (number < 0) {
           number = (-1) * number;
           ++length;
       }
       while (number) {
           number /= 10;
           length++;
       }
       return length;
   }
   ```

   <sup>Derived from granmirupa's answer.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether it fits your requirement but you could use std::to_string to convert your numeric data to string and then return its length.